# Designing new RK number for unique record

Tags: sas

I am a SAS Developer. I am starting a project that requires me to assign RK number to unique record. Every extraction will get data that is already existed in the target table and some may not.
For example.

Source Data:

```
Name
A
B
C
D
E
```

Target Table:

```
Name RK
A    1
B    2
C    3
```

When I load, i want it to insert D and E into the target table with RK 4 & 5 respectively. Currently, I can think of doing hash lookup from source with target table. For data that is not mapped using hash object, RK field will be blank. I will put the max RK number from the target table and incremental 1 to it by appending D & E into it.

I am not sure if this is the most efficient way of doing so. Is there another more efficient way?

Comment: Is there any risk of concurrency? in other words, say you have a stored process that involves performing this RK assignment task.  Can two users be running the same stored process at the same time ?

Comment: Hi richard, this is run in SAS Data Integration by batch. There shouldn't be any concurrent user for this. I understand about your concern and it is indeed a headache for stored process as I had encountered this problem not just with RK assignment but reading and writing the same table by 2 concurrent session that remains unsolved even after 1 year.

Comment: How many distinct names (values) will the target table have?

Comment: @Richard assuming target table have only 3 rows initially. It can grow up to 100k records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* use a hash to determine if some name (I'll call it *value*) already exists in target table.  However, new keys would have to be tracked, output at the end of the step and then PROC APPPEND'd to target table (I'll call it *master*) .

For the case of just updating the master table with new RK values, a traditional SAS approach is to use a DATA step to MODIFY a unique keyed master table.  The coding pattern is:

```
  SET <source>
  MODIFY <master> KEY=<value> / UNIQUE;
  ... _IORC_ logic ...
```

**Example:**

%* Create some source data and the master table;

```
data have1 have2 have3 have4 have5;
  call streaminit(123);

  value = 2020; output; output; output;

  do _n_ = 1 to 2500;
    value = ceil(rand('uniform', 5000));
    select;
      when (rand('uniform') < 0.20) output have1;
      when (rand('uniform') < 0.20) output have2;
      when (rand('uniform') < 0.20) output have3;
      when (rand('uniform') < 0.20) output have4;
      otherwise output have5;
    end;
  end;
run;

data have6;
  do _n_ = 1 to 20;
    value = 2020;
    output;
  end;
run;

* Create the unique keyed master table;
* Typically done once and stored in a permanent library.;

proc sql;
  create table keys (value integer, RK integer);
  create distinct index value on work.keys;
quit;
```

%* A macro for adding new RK values as needed;

```
%macro RK_ASSIGN(master, data);
  %local last;
  proc sql noprint;
    select max(RK) into :last trimmed from &master;
  quit;

  data &master;
    retain newkey %sysevalf(0&last+0);  %* trickery for 1st use case when max(RK) is .;
    set &data;
    modify &master key=value / unique;
    if _iorc_ eq %sysrc(_DSENOM);
    newkey + 1;
    RK = newkey;
    output;
    _error_ = 0;
  run;
%mend;

%* Use the macro to process source data;

%RK_ASSIGN(keys,have1)
%RK_ASSIGN(keys,have2)
%RK_ASSIGN(keys,have3)
%RK_ASSIGN(keys,have4)
%RK_ASSIGN(keys,have5)
%RK_ASSIGN(keys,have6)
```

[image]

You can see the forced repeats of the `2020` value in the source data is only RK'd once in the master table, and there are no errors during processing.

If you want to *backfill* the source data with the found or assigned RK value there would be additional steps.  You could update a custom format, or do a traditional left join.  If you want to focus on *backfill* during a read over source data the HASH step + APPEND new RK's step might be preferable.

**Example 2** Master table is named `values`

HASH version with RK assignment added to source data.  New RKs output and appended.

```
proc sql;
  create table values (value integer, RK integer);
  create distinct index value on work.values;


%macro RK_HASH_ASSIGN(master,data);
  %local last;
  proc sql noprint;
    select max(RK) into :last trimmed from &master;
  quit;

  data &data(drop=next_RK);
    set &data end=end;

    if _n_ = 1 then do;
      declare hash lookup (dataset:"&master");
      lookup.defineKey("value");
      lookup.defineData("value", "RK");
      lookup.defineDone();

      declare hash newlookup (dataset:"&master(obs=0)");
      newlookup.defineKey("value");
      newlookup.defineData("value", "RK");
      newlookup.defineDone();
    end;

    retain next_RK %sysevalf(0&last+0);  %* trick;

    * either load existing RK from hash, or compute and apply next RK value;
    if lookup.find() ne 0 then do;
      next_RK + 1;
      RK = next_RK;
      lookup.add();
      newlookup.add();
    end;

    if end then do;
      newlookup.output(dataset:'work.newmasters');
    end;
  run;

  proc append base=&master data=work.newmasters;
  proc delete data=work.newmasters;
  run;
%mend;

%RK_HASH_ASSIGN(values,have1)
%RK_HASH_ASSIGN(values,have2)
%RK_HASH_ASSIGN(values,have3)
%RK_HASH_ASSIGN(values,have4)
%RK_HASH_ASSIGN(values,have5)
%RK_HASH_ASSIGN(values,have6)
```

%* Compare the two assignment strategies, no differences!;

```
proc sort force data=values(index=(value));
  by RK;
run;

proc compare noprint base=keys compare=values out=diffs outnoequal;
by RK;
run;
----- LOG -----
2525  proc compare noprint base=keys compare=values out=diffs 

outnoequal  <------------- do not output when data is identical ;

;
2526  by RK;
2527  run;

NOTE: There were 215971 observations read from the data set WORK.KEYS.
NOTE: There were 215971 observations read from the data set WORK.VALUES.
NOTE: The data set WORK.DIFFS has 0 observations and 4 variables.   <--- all the same ---
NOTE: PROCEDURE COMPARE used (Total process time):
      real time           0.25 seconds
      cpu time            0.26 seconds
```

Comment: You can tweak the `have` data generating code to simulate a higher volume of values. `do _n_ = 1 to 500000;
    value = ceil(rand('uniform', 250000));`

Comment: Thanks Richard. Hash here and your max RK +0 is really beneficial and informative to me. Really appreciate that and I will try it out tomorrow as soon as my environment is ready.